# Why do constructors live on stack instead of heap memory (Java), aren't they invoked on creation of an object?

Tags: java, memory-management, constructor, callstack, objectinstantiation

I'm doing a bit of a deep dive into Java programming. As I'm reading a book I realize that similar to methods and associated local variables (stack variables), constructors also get to stack series the same way as methods (on each call, the rack goes on top of the call stack, and then gets "popped off" on completion (end of code block "}"). Repeat the process until the rack at the bottom of the stack finishes executing all the statements.

So, what I would like to understand is how come constructors also go to the stack instead of the heap memory (gc heap), aren't they supposed to be members of the object being instantiated (live on heap too)?

I tried understanding, but couldn't.

Comment: because constructors are like a method in the JVM - they just have a special name (`<init>`) and the compiler creates almost¹ the same code as any method call, to call this method after the instance is created. || **¹** `invokespecial` instead of `invokevirtual`

Comment: so it doesn't matter to the JVM, whether there's any return type or not? since a constructor could be distinguished by it not having a return type

Comment: Regarding terminology, methods are also _members_ of a class/object, just like the constructor.

Comment: You are getting hung up on the details of syntax and trying to infer runtime behaviour from that. A constructor is basically (similar to) a `void` method, but you don't specify `void` when declaring it, because its specific syntax is what makes Java know it is a constructor.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I beg to differ: Java first creates (allocates memory for) the object, and then invokes the appropriate constructor for further initialization. The constructor itself doesn't create the object. See [JLS 15.9.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.4).

Comment: @user85421 Oh, so  'invokevirtual' must be for the non-special method

Comment: [JVM Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokevirtual)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I suggest you make an Answer with that interesting info.

Comment: Thanks for the info, everyone. @MarkRotteveel see that I've been considering a constructor-method as if it's not a method and also, as not a "member" of an object. I would like to learn more about this. Currently, I'm reading Head First Java, is there any book/resource that gets into detail regarding this topic, that you could recommend?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Ab12 to be exact, the virtual machine will not call the constructor, but an *initializer* that includes instance initializers, instance variable initializer and the constructor

Comment: @BasilBourque I considered that, but there are IMHO too many misconceptions underlying the question, and I'm not sure how to address them.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel please point out what I'm missing, I would like to learn from that